How to expect a specific Typescript function template as an Angular component input
I have one Angular component  which has the following input
@Input() filterColumnFunction?: FilterColumnFunction;

This function type ('template') is the following
export type FilterColumnFunction = <T>(columnFilters: { [key: string]: string }, items: T[]) => T[];

The given function to the component is
filterColumnFunction = (columnFilters: { [key: string]: string }, items: MyDto[]): MyDto[] => {
    return items.filter((item) => item.name === 'test');
};

but when I call the component with this function as input, I always get the following error
<my-component [filterColumnFunction]="filterColumnFunction"></my-component>


`Type '(columnFilters: { [key: string]: string }, items:
MyDto[]) =>
MyDto[]' is not assignable to type
'FilterColumnFunction'

I don't understand why my function is not considered as the FilterColumnFunction type and what I can do to make this work ?

The location of the generic type<T> should be before the assignment of the type.
export type FilterColumnFunction<T> = (
  columnFilters: { [key: string]: string },
  items: T[]
) => T[];

Full Code:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export interface MyDto {
  name: string;
}

export type FilterColumnFunction<T> = (
  columnFilters: { [key: string]: string },
  items: T[]
) => T[];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class Child {
  @Input() filterColumnFunction?: FilterColumnFunction<MyDto>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
    <app-child [filterColumnFunction]="filterColumnFunction"></app-child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  filterColumnFunction: FilterColumnFunction<MyDto> = (
    columnFilters: { [key: string]: string },
    items: MyDto[]
  ): MyDto[] => {
    return items.filter((item: MyDto) => item.name === 'test');
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

That works perfectly, thank you to explain my mistake !
